# Force deriving from a class virtually

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, virtual-inheritance, static-assert

We have a special framework for interfaces in our project, and part of the requirements is that classes which represent an interface may only be used as virtual base classes, not as non-virtual ones. Is there a way to enforce this in code? That is, produce a compilation error if the class is derived from non-virtually.

I have access to C++11 as implemented by VS 2010: this means `static_assert`, `enable_if` and `<type_traits>` are available.

Comment: There might be better ways to do this now, but in VS2010 there is a Microsoft specific keyword called `__interface`. However this is a) not portable and b) You have to be careful since for some reason these interfaces are not allowed to have a virtual destructor.

Comment: This sounds more like a technical specification than a functional requirement. Why do you need this?

Comment: @Excelcius We're developing for Linux as well as Windows; I listed VS2010, because gcc is ahead in C++11 support.

Comment: @PeterWood The virtually-only requirement was introduced to avoid diamond-inheritance problems when deriving implementation classes, without the need to use bridges. As for why I want a compile-time error, that's to 1) reduce space for reviewers failing to notice a violation, and 2) help when converting old code to this new requirement.

Comment: @Angew Ok so that's no option. Didn't want to post it as an answer anyway because there are very different opinions on `__interface`. It causes more problems than it really solves.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. To even start this, you'd need some way of enumerating what classes are being inherited from at compile time, and there is no way of doing that (at least not that I know of).

Comment: Does it need to be enforced at compile time? You could [write a little tool using libclang](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/) to check, and use it as part of your code review/build process.

Comment: @PeterWood Nice idea, I wouldn't have thought of that. I don't think I would be given time to do that, but it would certainly be a solution to the problem.

Comment: With `virtual` inheritance you will *get* diamond inheritance (with its problems); without virtual inheritance you won't have diamond inheritance problems, you will have duplicated base classes instead (with that set of problems instead).

Comment: If I can figure out how to make a class `X` only be able to be inherited directly from friends, and be able to be inherited indirectly from anyone (even `virtual`ly), I could solve this.  Can't figure out that step quite (private destructors with friends blocks indirect virtual inheritance).

Comment: If a class is really only an interface, that is it has no method implementations or member variables, it shouldn't matter if it is inherited virtually or not.

Comment: @Clark not true.  If it is inherited non-virtually, you could have two instances of that class in the hierarchy, with two implementations, and casting to that interface can result in different methods being used for the same object.  This could be highly confusing and unexpected behavior.  If it is `virtual` everywhere, then any class that implements a method implements it for the entire hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, there is no clean and platform independent solution available to this problem.

The best way is to manually go and change each and every inheritance to `virtual` inheritance.
To accomplish that, identifying the derived classes of your interface (say `class Base`) is easy(!). Below steps can be followed for that:

1. Make `class Base` as `final` (c++11); i.e. `class Base final { ...`
2. Compile the code, it will generate compiler error for all its
   derived classes
3. Go and check every derived class and make the inheritance as
   `virtual`
4. Remove the `final` keyword and compile the code successfully

This process (unfortunately) has to be followed periodically, whenever you want to do such sanity checking.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible to check at compile time. The key is that, if we have a diamond pattern:

[image: diamond]

You can unambiguously cast `D&` to `A&`. However, if the inheritance is non-virtual:

[image: not diamond]

the cast would ambiguous. So let's try to make a diamond!

```
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
class make_diamond {
    struct D2 : virtual Base { }; // this one MUST be virtual
                                  // otherwise we'd NEVER have a diamond
public:
    struct type : Derived, D2 { };
};
```

At which point it's just another [`void_t`](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3911.pdf)-style type trait:

```
template <typename Base, typename Derived, typename = void> 
struct is_virtual_base_of : std::false_type { };

template <typename Base, typename Derived>
struct is_virtual_base_of<Base, Derived, void_t<
    decltype(static_cast<Base&>(
        std::declval<typename make_diamond<Base, Derived>::type&>()))
    >> : std::true_type { };
```

If the cast is unambiguous, the expression in the partial specialization will be valid, and that specialization will be preferred. If the cast is ambiguous, we'll have a substitution failure, and end up with the primary. Note that `Base` here doesn't actually need to have any `virtual` member functions:

```
struct A { };
struct B : public A { };
struct C : virtual  A { };

std::cout << is_virtual_base_of<A, B>::value << std::endl; // 0
std::cout << is_virtual_base_of<A, C>::value << std::endl; // 1
```

And if it has any pure virtual member functions, we don't have to override them since we're never actually constructing an object.

```
struct A2 { virtual void foo() = 0; };
struct B2 : public A2 { void foo() override { } };
struct C2 : virtual A2 { void foo() override { } };

std::cout << is_virtual_base_of<A2, B2>::value << std::endl; // 0
std::cout << is_virtual_base_of<A2, C2>::value << std::endl; // 1
```

Of course if your class is marked `final`, this won't work at all. But then, if it were `final`, it wouldn't matter what kind of inheritance it had anyway.

Comment: I know simpler approaches to check whether or not a base class is virtual (e.g. casting, pointer-to-member conversions etc.) but those are affected by the accessibility of the base class. Your approach using ambiguity checking is not affected by access protection, so +1. However, it is affected by already existing ambiguities, e.g. `struct D : B, C {};` So `is_virtual_base_of` is something like `is_nonfinal_unambiguous_virtual_base_of` ;)

Comment: @dyp Not sure what you mean by existing ambiguities?

Comment: `D d; A& a = d;` is ambiguous: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d92de17312866f0b

Comment: @dyp 0, 1, 0 seems right tho, annoying gcc warning notwithstanding.

Comment: Well, `A` is a virtual base of `D`, so I'd expect `is_virtual_base_of<A, D>::value` to be true. On the other hand, the current behaviour is probably more useful for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem.  You may be able to get close to what you want by hiding the interface class and exposing a concrete class that inherits from the interface virtually.  This obviously entails some workarounds and awkwardness, but it might be adaptable to your needs.  Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Hide {
    struct VInterface {
        void foo() const { cout << "VInterface::foo()\n"; }
        VInterface const &as_interface() const { return *this; }
    protected:
        virtual ~VInterface() { }
    };
public:
    struct VBase : virtual VInterface {
    };
};
typedef Hide::VBase VBase;
struct VDiamond1 : VBase { };
struct VDiamond2 : VBase { };
struct VConcrete : VDiamond1, VDiamond2 { };

int main() {
    VConcrete vc;
    auto const &vi = vc.as_interface();
    vi.foo();
}
```

It may be possible to reconstruct a name using `decltype()` and `as_interface()` that may be usable for inheritance, but the ones I tried resulted in compiler errors that the destructor was protected, so I expect that if it is possible, it's at least relatively difficult and might be sufficient for your needs.